# Type casting within a recursive function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, casting, type-conversion

I am learning Haskell and recursion and different types in Haskell is making my brain hurt. I am trying to create a recursive function that will take a 32 bit binary number string and convert it to a decimal number. I think my idea for how the recursion will work is fine but implementing it into Haskell is giving me headaches. This is what I have so far:

```
bin2dec :: String -> Int
bin2dec xs = ""
bin2dec (x:xs) = bin2dec xs + 2^(length xs) *  x
```

The function is supposed to take a 32 bit number string and then take off the first character of the string. For example, "0100101010100101" becomes "0" and "100101010100101". It then should turn the first character into a integer and multiply it by 2^length of the rest of the string and add it to the function call again. So if the first character in the 32 bit string is "1" then it becomes 1 * 2^(31) + recursive function call.

But, whenever I try to compile it, it returns:

```
traceProcP1.hs:47:14: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Int'
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    * In the expression: ""
      In an equation for `bin2dec': bin2dec xs = ""
   |
47 | bin2dec xs = ""
   |              ^^

traceProcP1.hs:48:31: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Char'
    * In the second argument of `(+)', namely `2 ^ (length xs) * x'
      In the expression: bin2dec xs + 2 ^ (length xs) * x
      In an equation for `bin2dec':
          bin2dec (x : xs) = bin2dec xs + 2 ^ (length xs) * x
   |
48 | bin2dec (x:xs) = bin2dec xs + 2^(length xs) *  x
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I know this has to do with changing the datatypes, but I am having trouble type casting in Haskell. I have tried type casting x with read and I have tried making guards that will turn the '0' into 0 and '1' into 1, but I am having trouble getting these to work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the typing problems, it's worth pointing out that you've got the patterns in the wrong order. Matching goes top-down and stops at the first match - so once this is fixed so that it compiles, you'll get 0 for any string. You need to either switch the order, or change the pattern so that it doesn't catch everything, but just the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no casting. If you want to convert from one type to another, there needs to be a function with the right type signature to do so. When looking for any function in Haskell, Hoogle is often a good start. In this case, you're looking for [`Char -> Int`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Char%20-%3E%20Int), which has several promising options. The first one I see is `digitToInt`, which sounds about right for you.

But if you'd rather do it yourself, it's quite easy to write a function with the desired behavior, using pattern matching:

```
bit :: Char -> Int
bit '0' = 0
bit '1' = 1
bit c = error $ "Invalid digit '" ++ [c] ++ "'"
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! That makes much more sense. What would you do in a situation where there's not a small amount of options like 0 and 1 and you are trying to convert them all?

Comment: There's no way around it: pattern matching is the fundamental way to consume data in Haskell. You either need to write more patterns, or use some other function that already does that for you, like `ord :: Char -> Int`.

Comment: @EMC, `ord` comes from `Data.Char` and is the same (for characters) as the polymorphic `fromEnum` function available from the prelude (without imports). These functions don't actually match on all the possible characters; they use the internal representation of `Char` to do their jobs efficiently and compactly.